# End a conversation c# bot

Tags: c#, visual-studio, botframework, chatbot

I'm building a ChatBot in C# and I want that after some messages the conversation stop, but I don't know how to do it. I have already set a limit of messages, and I want that after the reach of this limit no more messages can be send. There is my code:

```
private int NombreDeMessages;

protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
{
    var message = await item;
    NombreDeMessages += 1; 

    if (message.Text != null && NombreDeMessages < 3)
    {
         await base.MessageReceived(context, item);
    } 
    else
    { 
         var reply = context.MakeMessage();
         await context.PostAsync(reply);
         context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }                
}
```

I deleted the HeroCard part because it is useless here.

The thing that I want is after the `context.Wait` at the end, add a end of conversation so the user can't talk more to the chatbot.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you I have solved my problem. I post the code if it can help someone !

```
private int NombreDeMessages;
        protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
        {
            var message = await item;
            NombreDeMessages += 1;
            string code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully;
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken);


            if (message.Text != null && NombreDeMessages < 3)
            {
                await base.MessageReceived(context, item);

            }
            else if (message.Text != null && NombreDeMessages == 3)
            {
                AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard();
                card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
                {
                    Text = "STOP FLOODING",
                    Weight = TextWeight.Bolder,
                    IsSubtle = true,
                    Wrap = true,
                    Size = TextSize.Large
                });

                card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
                {
                    Text = "You have reach the limit of queries",
                    IsSubtle = false,
                    Wrap = true,
                    Size = TextSize.Normal
                });

                card.Body.Add(new Image()
                {
                    Url = "http://images.roadtrafficsigns.com/img/dp/lg/traffic-stop-sign.png",

                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    Size = ImageSize.Stretch
                });

                Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
                {
                    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                    Content = card
                };
                var flood = context.MakeMessage();
                flood.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                await context.PostAsync(flood);

            }
            else
            {

                var reply = context.MakeMessage();

                reply.Type = ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation;
                reply.AsEndOfConversationActivity().Code = code;

                await context.PostAsync(reply, cancellationToken);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little ambiguous,What do you mean by **end conversation** do you want the user to never be able to talk to the chatbot again?  One thing you can do in the `else` block you have you can call `context.Done()` and remove your  `context.Wait(this.MessageReceived)`  that would allow your user to send messages but get no response, or in the case below let the user know the conversation has ended.

```
else
{ 

    var reply = context.MakeMessage();
    reply.Text = "conversation ended";
    await context.PostAsync(reply);
    context.Done(this);
}
```