# Restrict users to reply in Teams conversation using c#

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a bot and adding it to Microsoft Teams. Whenever a action happens bot will reply to that action in same conversation thread by i dont want user to reply to that thread again.
So is this possible to restrict user to reply to a specific conversation using c#.

Comment: Kindly provide the code which you have achieved so far so that others can help you out.

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242016/end-a-conversation-c-sharp-bot

Comment: If you want to block the fact that the user can reply to the same message thread, I guess it's not possible. But not 100% sure